# What's the point of "A Kingdom Past"?

Tags: super-mario-run

It seems to indicate that you should replicate the Kingdom, based on this image, but nothing seems to happen when you do. What's the point of this image?

[image]

Comment: I tried this too but there are a couple items that don't exist in the store and the green pipe is a different size.

Comment: Also, I just bought the cake (most expensive special item) and once you get it the cake sits in front of the castle and you can't move it.

Comment: To get the white flowers you have to link a Nintendo account and buy them with Mario coins in My Nintendo. Maybe Nintendo just wants you to register an account...

Comment: BTW the picture is the same for all users. Mine is identical.

Comment: Have you reached the maximum level, yet? Maybe it's necessary to complete reconstruction on the castle.

Comment: @JacobKrall When you reach the maximum level, the castle changes from the one in this picture, so it's impossible to recreate exactly :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this image is just supposed to be a reminder of how the kingdom was before it was destroyed, to save people who want it to be back how it was from having to get a screenshot of it from a new game.

Comment: Various sources on the Web seem to confirm this. There's no secret to the pictute. It's for reference only.